# How to handle KeyError with asynchronous load_balanced_view results in ipyparallel?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, ipython-parallel

Using the `customresults.py` file in the ipyparallel examples directory, but with my own heavy computation that returns a giant Python dict, I'm getting

```
KeyError(u'81e440ca-59cc-4fed-a798-d2a78cc274e6')
KeyError(u'7ec312ed-7824-4d2a-8ec1-ab38fc8670af')
KeyError(u'9df55894-4bb7-4ac4-bd07-9d11f3d178d3')
KeyError(u'7f3d0293-e434-405e-9795-8303f322f102')
KeyError(u'a5819584-27e3-4364-8a12-67cbfe0ac43f')
KeyError(u'e37f5be4-4ca0-49b0-ad7a-f970672d3d09')
```

Is it possible to re-submit these failed jobs? I'm not sure what is going on here.

Thanks!